# PostgreSQL json_agg, and trying to group by and order by (column must appear in GROUP BY)

Tags: postgresql

I've read several of the stackoverflow's about this error, but I still don't get it.

```
-- Returns full JSON document of a user, and all their user_files.
with user_files_json as (
    select user_id,
           json_agg(
             json_build_object(
               'user_file_id', user_file_id,
               's3_key', s3_key,
               'settings', series_settings
             )
           ) as user_files
      from user_files
     where user_id = :user_id
  group by user_id
  order by user_file_id asc
)
select json_build_object(
         'user_id', user_id,
         'user_name', user_name,
         'job_type_name', job_type_name,
         'user_files', user_files
       )
  from user_files_json
  join users using(user_id)
  join job_type using(job_type_id);
```

I want the files to list in order by their user_file_id. That's all. If I take out the `order by` things work, but files come out in the wrong order.

But I get an error saying:

```
column "user_files.user_file_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

What I'm telling postgresql makes perfect sense to me as a human, but can someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So you want to sort the JSON objects by `user_file_id`. You’ll have to first create the JSON objects and then group and aggregate those, because PostgreSQL is only returning the aggregate and `user_id` and those can’t be sorted based on what’s inside the aggregate, only what’s in the resulting set.

```
select user_id,
       json_agg(obj) as user_files
  from (
    select user_id, json_build_object(
           'user_file_id', user_file_id,
           's3_key', s3_key,
           'settings', series_settings
      order by user_file_id asc
         ) as obj
  from user_files
 where user_id = :user_id) tmp
group by user_id
```

Comment: I still don't entirely get why, but thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I'm getting the following error: `ERROR:  syntax error at or near ":"`

Comment: That's a variable you have to replace `:user_id`

Answer (score 0):

ERROR: ORDER BY specified, but json_build_object is not an aggregate function
This is the error you get if you try sorting by a specific column inside json_build_object.
Instead try the following and it works

```
select user_id,
       user_files
  from (
    select user_id, json_agg(json_build_object(
           'user_file_id', user_file_id,
           's3_key', s3_key,
           'settings', series_settings)order by user_file_id asc) as user_files
  from user_files
 where user_id = :user_id) tmp
group by user_id
```